# efficient way to JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql

I have to JOIN two tables: articles and sales, but not all the data of articles, just need the last load.

Is there a difference between this two ways? there is a most faster/efficient way? and more important, why?

1)

```
SELECT *
FROM sales S
INNER JOIN articles A
ON S.article_id = A.article_id AND A.load_date = (SELECT MAX(load_date) FROM articles)
```

2)

```
SELECT *
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM articles
    WHERE load_date = (SELECT MAX(load_date) FROM articles)
) A
ON s.article_id = a.article_id
```

Comment: The SQL engine will optimize your query before executing it so they will both be about as fast.  Stick with option 1 because it is simpler and easier to read .

Comment: This is environment dependent.  You will need to look at the RDBMS' execution plan to see precisely which is preferable.  I agree with Martian that #1 is more readable and more common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most DBMSes also support Windowed Aggregate Functions and a RANK might be more efficient (and easier to write if you're used to it):

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT *,
     RANK()  -- max date gets rank #1
     OVER (PARTITION BY a.article_id
           ORDER BY a.load_date DESC) rn
   FROM sales s
   INNER JOIN articles a
   ON s.article_id = a.article_id
 ) dt
WHER rn = 1
```